# Vue Bootstrap, how to interact with plus/minus icon on dynamic generated collapse content separately

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a VueJS view that creates collapsed contents using [Bootstrap Vue Collapse Component](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse).
The data is dynamic and can contains hundreds of items, which is why you see in the code below it was created via a v-for loop in Vue.

```html
<div class="inventory-detail" v-for="(partNumberGroup,index) in inventory" :key="index" >
   <b-button block v-b-toggle="partNumberGroup.partNumber" v-bind:id="partNumberGroup.partNumber" variant="primary"
      @click="(evt) =>{isActive = !isActive &&  evt.target.id == partNumberGroup.partNumber}">
      <i v-bind:id="partNumberGroup.partNumber" class="float-right fa" :class="{ 'fa-plus': !isActive, 'fa-minus': isActive }"></i>
      {{ partNumberGroup.partNumber }}
   </b-button>
   <div class="inventory-detail__card" v-for="item in partNumberGroup.items">
      <b-collapse v-bind:id="partNumberGroup.partNumber"  >
         <b-card>
            <!--Accordion/Collapse content -->
         </b-card>
      </b-collapse>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works fairly well in that I can individually expand and collapse each content separately.  However, the one issue I'm facing is each time I click the icon fa-minus (-) orfa-plus (+), all of them changed as per the images below.

Any tips on how I should implementing this? in my code I tried the dynamic CSS class switching but I still lack the ability to switch on specific element.

I feel like the solution to this is to somehow conditionally apply dynamic CSS class or somehow able to use the attribute 'aria-expanded'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the contents of `isActive` method, that's probably where the problem lies.

Comment: my isActive is just a variable that set to false.   the only other place is in the code where each time you click on the button it changes the isActive to !isActive.   I agree with you that is really the root of this problem where all the element will set  when isActive changes ....that's why i think I must use something that uniquely identify each accordion and not just rely on isActive alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. Whenever somebody clicks on the icon, set its index as `activeIndex` (using the `setActiveIndex` method). Then you can set the class accordingly by comparing the `activeIndex` with current index

```
<i 
    @click="setActiveIndex(index)" 
    v-bind:id="partNumberGroup.partNumber" 
    class="float-right fa" 
    :class="{ 'fa-plus': !isActive(index), 'fa-minus': isActive(index) }">. 
</i>
```

then in the script part:

```
...

data() {
    return {
        activeIndex: -1
    }
},
methods: {
   /* set active index on click */
   setActiveIndex(index) {
       this.activeIndex = index;
   },
   /* check if index is active or not */
   isActive(index) {
       return index === this.activeIndex;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there are still some odd behavior when clicking on the same item twice but this definitely gave me the base to go on.

Comment: Glad it helped.